# Convert xml into HL7 format

Tags: android, ios, titanium, hex, hl7

I am working on a telehealth device showcase.

I have found Mirth Connect but no able to get hold on it that much. Is there any other api or frees source or library which can be used on our android client to convert xml into HL7 or any other format to HL7.

Comment: Are these 3 different questions?

Comment: i guess I hv clearly marked the q mark in 3 point..

Answer (score 2):

It seems no one wants to speak up so I'll try. First of all, there are two distinct HL7 formats – HL7v2 and HL7v3. So your first question would be – I have some data stored in the database (in a flat file in the XML format; in a flat file in JSON; etc) and I’d like to map it to HL7v2/HL7v3/CDA/etc.

Since both HL7v2 and HL7v3 cover multiple domains (e.g., Patient Administration, Medical Records, Genomics, etc.) your next question would be to specify what you are trying to achieve. If it’s a single domain solution, i.e., Pharmacy Dispensing System notifications or a full-fledged multi-domain solution.

The next one, what open-source system to use if any – Mirth Connect or something else. It also depends on where the data mapping or transformation is done – on the client side or on the server side (i.e., you can send a request message in your own format and transform it to the HL7 on the server side before passing to other players).

I presume, and I might be incorrect, we are talking about the patient demographic data using HL7v2 running on a patient's mobile phone. The Mirth Connect, as your initial format to HL7v2 translator, may be Ok for prototyping, running as a black box somewhere, but for the real solution on the mobile phone it might be too excessive. If there are quite a few request messages I would build them as my own proprietary code. If your solution is more complex, then it requires reviewing the solution architecture to find out all transformation points and this goes a bit beyond than a discussion on this site.

Again, this is my very subjective opinion.

---

And the last, but not least, there is an "[Unofficial Mirth Connect Developer's Guide](http://mirthconnect.shamilpublishing.com)" book which may help in initial understanding what the Mirth Connect is capable of.

(Disclaimer: I'm the author of this book, so any comments or suggestions are welcome.)

Answer (score 0):

1. For creation of some simple HL7 v2 messages you don't need any special libraries or tools or as it is almost simple text piped format (actually it is a binary format but if you take care about correct segment delimiters and don't use other then ASCII characters then it is straightforward to create).

   Once you have the HL7 packet you can send it to an IP address with HL7 listening endpoint using the HL7 Minimal Lower Layer Protocol (MLLP).
2. Some open source code base that might be useful even on Adroid device are **Java** libraries used by the **[dcm4chee](http://www.dcm4che.org/confluence/display/proj/The+Project)** project.

   e.g. the [DICOM Clinical Data Manager system - image archive](http://www.dcm4che.org/confluence/display/ee2/Home) is able to communicate with both DICOM and HL7 systems and internally uses code that translates HL7 v2 messages into XML intermediate representation and back. Look for XSLT (*.xsl) transformation scripts.